# VB.NET datagridview for every x amount of rows do

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I've been surfing the web but cant seam to find the answer I'm looking for.

Ussing VB.net I have a datagridview and i want to be able to undertake an action of every fith row that exists.

so lets say I have a button if this is clicked vb.net counts the datagrid rows and for every fith row it comes across i want to have MsgBox ("there goes another five rows") apear.

lets say there are 12 rows then thats 2x my mesagebox will apear, but there are two remaining rows in that case i want a msgbox thats says MsgBox("remaining rows found")?

dose anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim Count As Integer = 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1

        If Count = 5 Then
            MsgBox("there goes another five rows")
            Count = 0
        End If

        Count += 1
    Next
    MsgBox(Count & "remaining rows found")
```